# Trying to pass event data to function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to pass some data to a function but I'm facing an issue with the code below. I can't seem to make it work when i try to use `$(this).data("id")` if I just use `ABC` as a value it works.

```
$(".printLabel").click({
    recordId: $(this).data("id")
},  printLabel);

function printLabel(event){
    var data = event.data;
    console.log(data.recordId);
}
```

Comment: `this` isn't what you think it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the object you provide `this` is a reference to the `window`, not the clicked element, hence the data attribute you're looking for is undefined.

Assuming that the `data` attribute is on the `.printLabel` element itself, you can retrieve it within the event handler directly without sending any event arguments. Try this:

```
$(".printLabel").click(function() {
    var recordId = $(this).data("id")
    console.log(recordId);
});
```

Comment: My issue is that i need to call the function from other than the "click" so to prevent to have duplicate code, i want the function seperate.

Comment: In which case define the function separately and have it take two parameters, the element to be updated and the `id` value. You can then call it in the `click` handler, and wherever else is needed.

Comment: @user2517737 You should provide concrete sample replicating your issue. I'm really not sure to understand what you mean/expect?!

Answer (score 0):

Why is it a problem calling the function in a more understandable manner? Also if you insist on passing an object, you need to use the object passed - `var data = event.data;` would not work either. Here is my suggestion using an object too:

```js
$(".printLabel").on("click",function() {
   printLabel( {recordId: $(this).data("id")});
});

function printLabel(passedObject){
    console.log(passedObject.recordId);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="printLabel" data-id="ID1">This is id1</div>
```